# Xml Serialize Object and Add Elements even when missing values

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I've created an object with 100+ elements and not all of them are showing up in the final XML after serialization.  What can I add to the [XmlElement] decorator to make sure it is in the final XML even if it is empty?

Comment: Thanks!  My google foo was failing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the "IsNullable" property

```
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public string MustBePresent;
```

However this also includes the xsi namespace and adds `xsi:nil = "true"` attribute to the element.